# Discord.js - TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

### This is my Discord bot code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = require('./settings.json').token;

client.on('ready',() => {
    console.log('\n\nI\'m Online, mate.\nVery online, indeed.\n');
});
// Showing (in console) that the bot is online.



var prefix = "-"
client.on('message', message => { // Messaging stuff - Chat commands etc.

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

    console.log('A command was found.')

    let args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);
    var argresult = args.join(' ');

    if (message.author.bot) return;
    // If bot is the author (prevent selfbot.)



    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'moffa')) { // Checks if bot is online and shows latency.
        message.channel.send(`**MOFFA!!** \`${Date.now() - message.createdTimestamp} ms delay.\``);
    } else



    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'moos')) { // Cross-server messaging.
        client.channels.get('censored').send('Cross-channel typing is working, yes.');
        message.channel.send('Look in <#censored>.')
    } else



    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'sg')) { // Set game.
        if (!argresult) argresult = null;
        client.user.setActivity(argresult)
        message.channel.send('Set `' + argresult + '` as activity.')
    } else



    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'ss')) { // Set status.
        if(!argresult) argresult = 'online';
        client.user.setStatus(argresult);
        message.channel.send('Updated status.')
    } else



    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'fnname')) { // Sends censored's name on Fortnite.
        message.channel.send('`censored` is <@!censored>\'s name on Fortnite');
    } else



    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'commands')) { // Shows a message with all commands. Update manually.
        message.channel.send('All the current commands are: `moffa`, `fnname` & `commands`. Ex. use: `' + prefix + 'moffa`.');
    }
});


client.login(token);
```

I get this error:

```
PS C:\Users\censored\Documents\Code\nodejs\discord bot 2> nodemon
[nodemon] 1.17.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
events.js:239
    throw new TypeError('"listener" argument must be a function');
    ^

TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function
    at _addListener (events.js:239:11)
    at Client.addListener (events.js:297:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\censored\Documents\Code\nodejs\discord bot 2\app.js:7:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

It does not specify where the error is, or how to fix it.

I am using Atom (newest version.)
Nodemon is something that allows me to bypass having to open and close the terminal for each time I refresh the bot.
It worked fine, until I tried to make a rich embed command.
When I removed the command I got this error.
Well, I got it while I was making it too.

**Help would be appreciated. Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your error clearly states that the error is happening on line seven.

```
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\censored\Documents\Code\nodejs\discord bot 2\app.js:7:8)
```

You have `client.on('')` on line 7, which expects a second argument as a function.

Also, there is no event that you're listening on in that line.